# Control Limits (stat)

Tags: statistics

An $\bar{x}$ chart is to be established based on standard values: $μ=600, σ=12, n=9.$ The control limits are based on $α$-risk of $0.01$.

What are the appropriate control limits? $$\\$$

This is what I have so far:

I know the mean/centerline = $600$.

I don't know which formula to use to find the control limits:

μ $\pm  z_\frac{α}{2}$$(\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}})$  **OR** μ $\pm  3(\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}})$

I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the condition. You are given $\bar x = 600$,and $\mu$ is not given . It seems there is a mistake somewhere in the wording of the problem. Any way, to proceed to the $99$ % confidence interval ( correspond to $\alpha = 0.01$ is: CI of $\mu$ is: $ = \left( \bar x - z_{\alpha/2}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar x + z_{\alpha/2}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)= \left(600 - 2.575\cdot \frac{12}{\sqrt{9}}, 600 + 2.575\cdot \frac{12}{\sqrt{9}}\right)= ...$

Comment: But isn't μ = 600 from the problem?

Comment: Note that $-z_{\alpha/2}=+2.576$. Thus the interval is $\left( \bar x + z_{\alpha/2}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar x - z_{\alpha/2}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$